# minimum versions of system dependencies required for ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, ARM architecture. Is there a documentation / command line tool where I can find out the minimum required versions of the system dependencies for proper functioning of ROS?

PS: `sudo apt-get update` would take care of it during installation, however I explicitly want to know the minimum versions. Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256212/minimum-versions-of-system-dependencies-required-for-ros?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a documentation / command line tool where I can find out the minimum required versions of the system dependencies for proper functioning of ROS?

I doubt there is something that documents *all* dependencies (as that would depend on authors of *all* packages doing that), but for some of the larger dependencies: [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0